# Selecting a date based upon non unique column data in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Any suggestion please........
This is where I completely stucked. I have no code to show what I have tried. Cause I couldn't think of a way to figure this out in sql? Somebody suggested me to use pivot (new to the concept...couldn't figure it out). 4 steps of Col5 makes a complete cycle. I have multiple steps processed and need the timing of a complete cycle. 1 step of a cycle may begin before completion of other.

Table A

```
Col1    Col2     Col3 Col4 Col4     Col5   Col6
 A       Date1     11     12   13     StepA   AA
 A       Date2     11     12   13     StepB   AA 
 A       Date3     11     12   13     StepC   AA
 A       Date4     11     12   13     StepD   AA
 A       dAte1     11     12   13     StepA   AC
 A       dAte2     11     12   13     StepB   AC 
 A       dAte3     11     12   13     StepC   AC
 A       daTe1     111    12   13     StepA   AB <=== Step is not completed    
 A       dAte4     11     12   13     StepD   AC <=== Step completed but other step started already
 A       daTe2     111    12   13     StepB   AB 
 A       daTe3     111    12   13     StepC   AB
 A       daTe4     111    12   13     StepD   AB
```

Expected OutPut Table (Result):

```
AA Date1  Date2  Date3  Date4
AC dAte1  dAte2  dAte3  dAte4
AB daTe1  daTe2  daTe3  daTe4
```

Comment: Is Col6 a unique, non-repeating identifier for the cycle?

Comment: Sorry forgot to mention. Its repeating and can't be an identifier.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410%28v=sql.105%29.aspx ?

Comment: Pivot won't help to make identifier column. Isn't it?

Comment: if Col6 is non-unique then how one can recognize full cycle?

Comment: Sorry if i confused you all, AA (col6) can't start new cycle until it's completed whereas AB could start before AA is completed. Only the way to figure out (though I may be wrong) I am thinking is to check the next immediate step for AA (A through D)in col5.

Answer (score 1):

The Query:

```
SELECT * FROM 
    (SELECT [Col1]
      ,[Col2]
      ,[Col3]
      ,[Col4]
      ,[Col41]
      ,[Col5]
      ,[Col6]
    FROM [dbo].[YourTable])p
PIVOT ( MAX(Col2) FOR Col5  IN ([StepA],[StepB],[StepC],[StepD]) ) PVT
```

The Output:

```
Col1    Col3    Col4    Col41   Col6    StepA   StepB   StepC   StepD
A       11      12      13      AA      Date1   Date2   Date3   Date4
A       11      12      13      AC      dAte1   dAte2   dAte3   dAte4
A       111     12      13      AB      daTe1   daTe2   daTe3   daTe4
```

You can choose which columns you require and which columns to remove in your final select.(regarding col3,Col4,Col41)

*******Based on the logic explained in the comments****************

/* Provided sample Data */

```
select * from #Testdata

COL1    Date                        COL2   COL3 COL4 COL5  COL6
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:19:52.8944000 3132    95  70   RFP    GSBE 
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:19:58.1445000 3132    95  70   SR     GSBE 
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:19:58.3164000 3132    95  70   RTP    GSBE 
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:19:58.3164000 3132    95  70   SoRe   GSBE
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:39:30.0501000 3132    95  70   RFP    GSBE 
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:39:30.0501000 3132    95  70   SR     GSBE 
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:39:30.3470000 3132    95  70   RTP    GSBE 
QMS14   2013-04-08 17:39:30.3470000 3132    95  70   SoRe   GSBE
```

/*Query assuming each Cycle happens in the same minute */

```
SELECT 
     COL1 
    ,COL2 
    ,COL3 
    ,COL4 
    ,COL6 
    ,[RFP]
    ,[SR]
    ,[RTP]
    ,[SoRe]
FROM (
    SELECT *
        ,DATEPART(MINUTE,DATE) DateMinute
        ,DENSE_RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY Col1 ORDER BY DATEPART(MINUTE,DATE)) [Rank]   FROM  #Testdata
        )a
    PIVOT ( MAX([DATE]) FOR COL5 IN ([RFP],[SR], [RTP],[SoRe] )) PVT
```

OUTPUT:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3 COL4   COL6    RFP                         SR                          RTP                         SoRe
QMS14   3132     95   70   GSBE     2013-04-08 17:19:52.8944000 2013-04-08 17:19:58.1445000 2013-04-08 17:19:58.3164000 2013-04-08 17:19:58.3164000
QMS14   3132     95   70   GSBE     2013-04-08 17:39:30.0501000 2013-04-08 17:39:30.0501000 2013-04-08 17:39:30.3470000 2013-04-08 17:39:30.3470000
```

Comment: Thanks S.A. It works but doesn't give all values if cycle repeats with same value. Any insight on the situation would be appreciated....PLZ!!!

Comment: is the date/datetime also repeating if the cycle repeats? it would be great If you provide a sample row for the case when the sequence repeats.

Comment: SA I am unable to attach data. How could I provide you data? When I copy the file it messes it up.

Comment: This is actual data.                                  QMS14|04/08/2013 17:19:52.8944|3132|95|70|RFP|GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:19:58.1445|3132|95|70|SR |GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:19:58.3164|3132|95|70|SoRe |GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:19:58.3164|3132|95|70|RTP|GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:39:30.0501|3132|95|70|RFP|GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:39:30.0501|3132|95|70|SR |GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:39:30.3470|3132|95|70|SoRe |GSBE
QMS14|04/08/2013 17:39:30.3470|3132|95|70|RTP|GSBE

Comment: Sorry SA! Data are on same line. Couldn't format it. A single line looks like:  QMS14|04/08/2013 17:19:52.8944|3132|95|70|RFP|GSBE

Comment: These data are inserted at sql server in a temp table. I don't have a control of this file. I can only play the data #temptable onwards.

Comment: The Pivot uses an Aggregation function( MAX, MIN etc.) for Pivoting the data. As all of your other fields have same value hence it picks up the Min/Max of the dates. One way I see out of this is your date field. Assuming that your Cycle Completes in the same Minute , I can partition your data set based on that then do the PIVOT. It will return 2 records for these 8 records. Basically the Problem is that your cycle doesn't have a marker/key field which identifies a unique cycle. If this kind of field is present then its easy , else the partition on the Minute part of the date is the only way.

Comment: (...Continued from previous comment) I see with your existing data, Nonetheless I am posting the query based on the above logic, hope it helps !

Comment: It's a step further, though a cycle completes within a minute, I had have situations where minute portion of DateTime differs and couldn't help me. See Ex:

Comment: (...Continued) CSWC 2013-06-03 13:28:56.4506000 2013-06-03 13:28:58.3164000 2013-06-03 13:29:00.8641000 2013-06-03 13:29:00.8641000

Comment: Well in these cases where the cycle oversteps a minute or spills to the next minute, it would show up as different records because of reasons mentioned already. But I am afraid that with the absence of any key/field to uniquely identify a cycle this is the only solution that looks close to what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

To me, it looks like the cycles are determined by combinations of four "steps" with the same tag in `col6`.  The data in the example only has one cycle per code, but the comments suggest there might be more than one.

How can we identify which cycle for a given code a record belongs to?  Well, one way is to assume that all the cycles with that code are complete and just enumerate the records by `col6, col5`.  This additional cycle sequence number is then used for aggregation.  For enumerating the sequences, I further assume that the dates are increasing over time.

Although a pivot can be used in this case, I think the aggregation method might be a bit clearer:

```
select col6, seqnum,
       MAX(case when col5 = 'StepA' then col2 end),
       MAX(case when col5 = 'StepB' then col2 end),
       MAX(case when col5 = 'StepC' then col2 end),
       MAX(case when col5 = 'StepD' then col2 end)
from (select a.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() over (partition by col6, col5 order by col2) as seqnum
      from a
     ) a
group by col6, seqnum
```

Comment: Thanks Gordon....Looks like I can achieve what I was looking for....only a way I was looking help from you was that StepD timimng doesn't come up no matter what I try and each results are coming up in different rows.